# Object variables still available of a thread after interrupting

Tags: java, multithreading

i have this thread

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {

private final String lala = "lala";

@Override
public void run() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value = scanner.next();
    while (!value.equals("stop") && !isInterrupted()) {
        value = scanner.next();
    }
    interrupt();
    System.out.println("exit");
}

public String getMe() {
    return lala;
}
```

}

and I wonder why I always can access to the method getMe() even when the Thread is already interrupted.

Why is that so? And is that always possible, even after days or will the Garbage Collector somewhen delete that object?

Comment: Threads have nothing to do with objects.  You're calling that method on your own thread.

Comment: First, `interrupted` is just a `boolean` flag on the `Thread` instance, it has no immediate effect on the thread. Second, a thread of execution is one thing and an instance of the `Thread` class is something completely different. It's reachable as long as you hold a reference to it, plus it's always reachable as `currentThread()` while the corresponding thread of execution is alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interrupt() just sets a special flag. In you case it doesn't do anything special.

> I wonder why I always can access to the method getMe() even when the Thread is already interrupted.

To do this you must have a reference to the ThreadA object and while you hold that reference you will always be able to call it.

> is that always possible, even after days or will the Garbage Collector somewhen delete that object

Yes, when the thread is not running, it is just a plain object like any other and it will exist as long as you hold a reference to it.